# Any alternative Way of Combination?

Tags: java, android, combinations

Let me explain you what i am actually trying to achieve.

I'm having a list of different type of parking spaces based on street. Suppose i have one street name i.e abc  and that street can contain combination of below

> parking type (Elderly, Disabled, Motorcyclist, Truck, Chartered,
>   Conventional)

and based on contain parking type i need to show different marker on map.

**What i have tried:**
I tried to use it with making combination of all parking type i.e 6!=720, if i go with it i need to make 720 test cases and becomes too lengthy

> Response from firebase: parking_space key contain list of different parking type

[image]

This method would called on getting data from firebase and iterator through all the parking type available on that street and set the type `true and vice versa`

```
private ArrayList<ParkingTypePojo> parkingTypeListPojo = new ArrayList<>();

private ParkingTypePojo parkingTypePojo;
private void evaluateMarkerType(ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> pack) {
boolean elderlyStatus = false;
boolean disabledStatus = false;
boolean cyclistStatus = false;
boolean motorcyclistStatus = false;
boolean truckStatus = false;
boolean charteredStatus = false;
boolean conventionalStatus = false;
for (int i = 0; i < pack.size(); i++) {

switch (pack.get(i).get(Constants.PARKING_TYPE).toString()) {
case "Elderly"://normal green
//1
elderlyStatus = true;
break;
case "Disabled"://senior disable blue
//2
disabledStatus = true;
break;
case "Cyclist"://cycle orange
//3
cyclistStatus = true;
break;
case "Motorcyclist"://moto prpl
//4
motorcyclistStatus = true;
break;
case "Truck"://truck yllw
//5
truckStatus = false;
break;
case "Chartered"://cet black
//6
charteredStatus = true;
break;
case "Conventional"://zona blue money
//7
conventionalStatus = true;
break;
default:
break;
}

}
parkingTypePojo = new ParkingTypePojo(elderlyStatus, disabledStatus, cyclistStatus, motorcyclistStatus, truckStatus, charteredStatus, conventionalStatus);
parkingTypeListPojo.add(parkingTypePojo);
}
```

> I have stored parking type based on street in pojo class

```
public class ParkingTypePojo {

    private boolean elderlyStatus;
    private boolean disabledStatus;
    private boolean cyclistStatus;
    private boolean motorcyclistStatus;
    private boolean truckStatus;
    private boolean charteredStatus;
    private boolean conventionalStatus;

    public ParkingTypePojo(boolean elderlyStatus, boolean disabledStatus, boolean cyclistStatus, boolean motorcyclistStatus, boolean truckStatus, boolean charteredStatus, boolean conventionalStatus) {
        this.elderlyStatus = elderlyStatus;
        this.disabledStatus = disabledStatus;
        this.cyclistStatus = cyclistStatus;
        this.motorcyclistStatus = motorcyclistStatus;
        this.truckStatus = truckStatus;
        this.charteredStatus = charteredStatus;
        this.conventionalStatus = conventionalStatus;
    }

    public boolean isElderlyStatus() {
        return elderlyStatus;
    }

    public boolean isDisabledStatus() {
        return disabledStatus;
    }

    public boolean isCyclistStatus() {
        return cyclistStatus;
    }

    public boolean isMotorcyclistStatus() {
        return motorcyclistStatus;
    }

    public boolean isTruckStatus() {
        return truckStatus;
    }

    public boolean isCharteredStatus() {
        return charteredStatus;
    }

    public boolean isConventionalStatus() {
        return conventionalStatus;
    }

}
```

Please suggest any alternative way to solve this problem except the combinations. Thank you

Comment: Can you confirm that your need is to have a method which selects a marker from a set of boolean ? Or is it about a query ?

Comment: Also, Why do you have 720 possibilities ? Order matters ? I think it is just 64 possibilities (2^6).

Comment: On the map, I need to set marker based on parking type on street and each combination of parking type  `Elderly, Disabled, Motorcyclist, Truck, Chartered, Conventional)`.  I need to show a different marker on the map. if you calculate the factorial of 6!=720 possibilities. is there any other alternative way. please suggest

Comment: What @T.Lucas is saying is that you have defined permutations. If you are looking strictly for combinations of all 6 parking types, then there would only be one as order doesn't matter. The other suggestion by T.Lucas is generating all possible combinations of sets of every length from 0 (the empty set) to 6, also known as the power set (Cardinality is 2^6 in this case).